# How do I redirect @expose('/') to @expose('/roll') by onclicking the button

Tags: python-3.x, flask, flask-admin

View class :

```
    from sqlalchemy import desc
    from datamodels.relational_tables import initialize_datamodels
    from dataaccess.postgresql.database import (session_scope)
    import datamodels.relational_tables
    from flask.ext.admin import Admin, BaseView, expose
    from akamai_env import get_akamai_config
    from flask import request
    import json
    from sqlalchemy.sql.functions import now
    from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for
    import logging
    _log = logging.getLogger(__name__)



    akamai_config = get_akamai_config()
    base_url = akamai_config['webserver']['base_url']


    class RollBack(BaseView):

        @expose('/')
        def fetch_healthy_dataset_from_db(self):

            initialize_datamodels()
            with session_scope() as session:
                epd_ip_dataset = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdIpDataset
                qry = session.query(epd_ip_dataset).filter_by(dataset_state='healthy').order_by(
                    desc(epd_ip_dataset.dataset_id)).all()

                qry_last = session.query(epd_ip_dataset).filter_by(dataset_state='healthy').order_by(
                    desc(epd_ip_dataset.dataset_id)).first()

                url = url_for('.return_rollback_ui')
                url_for('rollback.return_rollback_ui')
                return self.render('airflow/base.html',
                                   qry=qry,
                                   dataset_id=qry_last.dataset_id,
                                   base_url=base_url,
                                   url=url)

        @expose('/roll', methods=['POST'])
        def return_rollback_ui(self):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                #body_req = request.json
                body_req = request.get_data()
                _log.error("Body of the request is ", body_req)
                #data = json.dumps(body_req)
                #self.initalize_db(body_req)
                return '<html> <h1> Hi I am sending a response</h1></html>'

        def initalize_db(self, body):
            dataset_id = body

            epdumppushrollback = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdUmpPushRollback

            with session_scope() as session:
                epdumppushrollback_obj = epdumppushrollback()
                epdumppushrollback_obj.dataset_id = dataset_id
                epdumppushrollback_obj.record_id = ''
                epdumppushrollback_obj.operator_name = ''
                epdumppushrollback_obj.activation_flag = 'active'
                epdumppushrollback_obj.record_creation_time = now()
                epdumppushrollback_obj.start_time = now()
                epdumppushrollback_obj.end_time = ''
                session.add(epdumppushrollback_obj)
                session.flush()


    class RollBackResume(BaseView):

        # @expose('/')
        # def index(self):
        #     return self.render('airflow/dags.html')

        def fetch_audited_dataset_from_db(self):
            initialize_datamodels()
            with session_scope() as session:
                epd_ip_dataset = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdIpDataset
                qry = session.query(epd_ip_dataset).filter_by(dataset_state='audited'). \
                    order_by(desc(epd_ip_dataset.dataset_id)).all()
                return qry

        @expose('/')
        def return_resume_ui(self):
            qry = self.fetch_audited_dataset_from_db()
            return self.render('airflow/rollback_resume.html',
                               qry=qry,
                               base_url=base_url)

        @expose('/rollbackresume', methods=['POST'])
        def return_rollback_ui(self):
            if request.method == 'POST':
                body_req = request.json
                data = json.dumps(body_req)

        def fetch_from_db(self):

            dataset_id = None
            initialize_datamodels()
            with session_scope() as session:
                epd_ump_push_rollback = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdUmpPushRollback
                qry = session.query(epd_ump_push_rollback).filter_by(activation_flag='active'). \
                    order_by(desc(epd_ump_push_rollback.dataset_id)).first()
                if qry:
                    dataset_id = qry.dataset_id
                return dataset_id

        def write_to_db(self):

            dataset_id = self.fetch_from_db()
            epd_ump_push_rollback = datamodels.relational_tables.EpdUmpPushRollback

            with session_scope() as session:
                qry = session.query(epd_ump_push_rollback)
                for rows in qry:
                    if rows.dataset_id == dataset_id:
                        rows.activation_flag = 'inactive'
                        rows.end_time = now()
                        session.commit()
                        session.flush()
                        break

HTML Page : 
<html>
<style>
p
{
    opacity: 0;
}

</style>
<head>
  <title>Roll back UI</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{base_url}}/admin/">Airflow</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/">DAGs</a></li>
      <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Data Profiling <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/queryview/">Ad Hoc query</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/chart/">Charts</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/knownevent/">Known Events</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Browse <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/slamiss/">SLA Instances</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/taskinstance/">Task Instances</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/log/">Logs</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/basejob/">Jobs</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/dagrun/">DAG Runs</a></li>

        </ul>
      </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Admin <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/pool/">Pools</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/configurationview/">Configuration</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/user/">Users</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/connection/">Connections</a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/variable/">Variables</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/xcom/">XComs</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Rollback <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/rollback/">Rollback </a></li>
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/rollbackresume/">Resume</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Docs <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Documentation</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Github</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>

        <li class="dropdown"><a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="{{base_url}}/admin/versionview/">Version</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <h3>RollBack UI</h3>
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col" >Dataset Id</th>
        <th scope="col">Dataset State</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
     {% for i in qry%}
            <tr>
                <th scope="row"> </th>
               <td> {{ i.dataset_id }} </td>
               <td> {{ i.dataset_state }} </td>
            </tr>
     {% endfor %}

    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
   <head>
<div class="container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="loadDoc()" id="myBtn"> Rollback to {{dataset_id}} </button>
</div>
  <p id="dataset_id"> {{ dataset_id }}</p>

<script>
function loadDoc()
{
  document.getElementById("myBtn").disabled = true;
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var dataset_id = document.getElementById("dataset_id");

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8085/admin/rollback/roll/", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
  xhttp.send("foo=bar&lorem=ipsum");
}
</script>
   </head>
<body>

<h2> Url of the index is {{ url }} </h2>

</body>>
</html>
```

Explanation of code :

I have class `RollBack` which returns a table after querying the database, there is a button present on that page; when I click on that button, I want to post some data to an endpoint which I am doing using `XMLHttpRequest` in the html page.

When I click on that button, the post data is directing me to `@expose('/')` method instead of `@expose('/roll')`, since `@expose('/')` method doesn't support post method it is throwing 405 error. I want my onclick action of button to redirect to `@expose('/roll')` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that your code is throwing a 405 is because you haven't configured your expose function to handle POST methods. The default is to handle only GET as explained in the [docs](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_base/#flask_admin.base.expose).

Your code logic should look something like the following:

from flask import request

```
class RollBack(BaseView):

    @expose('/',  methods=('GET', 'POST'))
    def fetch_healthy_dataset_from_db(self):

        if request.method == 'POST':
            #  Anything within this block is processing a POST method

             # make sure you eventually return a view
            return "Success"

        #  Anything after this point is processing a GET method
```